# C# Capture Keyboard Keys when focuse in a game

Tags: c#, logging, capture

I coded a program to capture keys from any application.Now it works when I'm in any window an other applications, but when I'm in a game like dirt3 even run window form mode , when I press keys it just doesn't do it, I have to `alt+tab` and than press the keys and it'll work. Is there any way to make it so the key capture priority of the program is absolute, aka more important than  will be capture even if I am in game?
Thanks

```
  private static LowLevelKeyboardProc _proc = HookCallback;
  private static IntPtr _hookID = IntPtr.Zero;

private static IntPtr SetHook(LowLevelKeyboardProc proc)
    {
        using (Process curProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
        using (ProcessModule curModule = curProcess.MainModule)
        {
            return SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, proc,
                GetModuleHandle(curModule.ModuleName), 0);
        }
    }
protected static IntPtr HookCallback(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        if (nCode >= 0 && wParam == (IntPtr)WM_KEYDOWN)
        {
            int vkCode = Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam);

            commandStr += ((Keys)vkCode);
            if (commandStr.ToLower().Contains("ooff"))
            {// do it work

           }
        }

        return CallNextHookEx(_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }
```

Comment: I guess there are some sort of function within the game itself that prohibits you to track the keypress of the user. Maybe some sort of anti cheat mechanism embedded in this games. Just a hypothesis.

Comment: I'm not sure what you real problem is. HookCallback is probably the way you need to go. But when you process a key, you should not allow to process the same key press event in OS. (Or process only the key event that need to be processed.) But don't forget that the processing of 'Ctrl+Alt+Del' is absolute (by OS) and that you need to correctly handle the situation when you game is running and you are outside of your app/game. You can open a mail, but all the key events will go to the game and not to the mail on incorrect implementation.